# What is the best way to return a list and integer from a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, class

I have a function that reads a csv gives me a list. Then, I find the max value of that list and then return that list and max value from a function. I want to know the best method to do this to make my code more efficient and more readable. I am still kinda new to python and I am trying to build my skill set using best practices. Currently, I have:

```
def getLayerList(layersLoc):
    import csv
    layerList = []
    reader = csv.reader(open(layerLoc))
    for list in reader:
        for layer in list:
            layerList.append(int(layer))
    numLayers = max(layerList)
    return layerList, numLayers
```

I can call both layer list and numLayers as [0],[1] instances of that function. My concern is that if I'm returning more and more different types of data it will be hard to track them and will get very hard to read them. Should I use a class instead? What would be the more *Pythonic* way to do this?

Comment: It is perfectly "pythonic" to return more than one value in a function. You can then externally call it like `myLayerList, myNumLayers = getLayerList(myLayersLoc)`, which is very readable. If you return many different things then it might be confusing, but then again maybe that's not a great design. There are also things like [named tuples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#namedtuple-factory-function-for-tuples-with-named-fields) or [data classes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) if you want to group things in a "lightweight class".

Comment: I don't really know what's "pythonic", but if you mean what's efficient, quick, and easy-to-understand, here's what I always do. If I want to return multiple values I return it as a tuple. Suppose the list is `List` and the value is `Value`. Then I would make the return line: `return (List, Value)`. One I do that, I can quickly use tuple unpackaging to assign each value in the list to a variable once I call the function, such as: `(Listname, ValueName) = func()`. This would not result in a tuple with both the characters, but with two variables equal to the values the function returned.

Comment: Gotcha thanks I'll keep it the way it is for now. I will look into named tuples and data classes.

Comment: In a sense, a permanent tuple is never created, the function returns a tuple, and you just assign multiple variables to each of the values in the tuple. However, if you say something like: `VarName = func()` and `func()` returns a tuple, `VarName` will be a tuple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a performance perspective, the first thing I'd avoid is calling `import` in the function itself. Doing an import at the top level will avoid repeated checks against `sys.modules` to see if a module has been imported.

Next, calling `max` after your iteration effectively iterates over that list again. I'd keep track of a max value inside your loop to avoid a second iteration over your list.

Last, I'd use a `with` statement to open the file, that way you know that the file remains open during the lifetime of the `reader`, which could actually be handled outside the function

```py
# imports go up here unless you have a very specific reason not to
import csv

# naming should be snake_case
def get_layer_list(my_reader):
    layer_list = []
    num_layers = 0

    # don't shadow builtin names like list
    for lst in my_reader:
        for layer in lst:
            val = int(layer)

            # do that check here
            if val > num_layers:
                num_layers = val

            layer_list.append(val)

    # now, num_layers has already been checked
    return layer_list, num_layers


with open('somefile.csv') as fh:
    reader = csv.reader(fh)

    # this is how you'd call the function
    layers, nlayers = get_layer_list(reader)

# do something with layers and nlayers
```

Otherwise, multiple values in a return is perfectly pythonic. What is *un*pythonic would be to index the returned values, when tuple unpacking is usually sufficient.

```py
# instead of this
x = return_two_values()
a = x[0]
b = x[1]

# do this
a, b = return_two_values()
```

Comment: I didn't think about how max worked, that is a good idea thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the most efficient, best way to do this would be to return all your values as part of a tuple. In your code, this would be:

```
def getLayerList(layersLoc):
    import csv
    layerList = []
    reader = csv.reader(open(layerLoc))
    for list in reader:
        for layer in list:
            layerList.append(int(layer))
    numLayers = max(layerList)
    return (layerList, numLayers) # Return the values as a tuple
```

This way, when you return it, you can do something like:

```
 (layerList, numLayers)=getLayerList(LayersLoc)
```

Which wil make it so `layerList` and `numLayers` will be equal to the values the function returns. They will NOT be part of a tuple.

Comment: `return` without the parentheses accomplishes the same thing. Check your indentation

Comment: Yeah, but sometimes I feel the parentheses make it a little bit more organized and easy for me to read, though. It's just another way of doing it.

Comment: As the Zen of Python goes, "Readability Counts"

Answer (score 1):

With Python, it's a good practice to make your functions as short as possible. This way, it's easier to understand and more modular. This is how I would write it without using a class:

```
import csv


def openFile(layerLoc):
    with open(layerLoc) as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file)
        return reader

def findMax(layerList):
        numLayers = max(layerList)
        return numLayers

def createLayerList(reader):
        layerList = []
        for list in reader:
                for layer in list:
                    layerList.appendLayer(layer)
        return layerList

if __name-- == '__main__':
    LayerList = [] 
    filename = "someFile.csv"
    reader = openFile(filename) 
    LayerList = getLayerList(reader)
    numLayers = findMax(layerList)
```

Comment: Your `openFile` function will cause a `ValueError` because the file-handle will be closed. The `return` closes the `with` statement calling `__exit__`, which in turn will do `fh.close()`. It would probably be better to `yield from reader` to create an iterator in that case, which keeps the handle open until you are done iterating